# How to preserve an Excel chart when table filtering changes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a fairly large table in Excel.  I take several filtering steps, then make a chart from the filtered data.  I have several more charts to create, so I un-filter the data to make a new chart.  But then the old chart changes completely.  Not only the formats, but the actual data that is plotted.  Is there any way to preserve the chart when the filtering changes?  Using Excel 2010, if it matters.

Comment: Try this,,, hit `File,,, Option,, Formula, set Calculating Option,, Manual`,,, and then after Excel will stop updating related Chart,,, while Filter,, data Update ! If using older version then try  `Formula,, Calculation,, Options,, Manual.`

Comment: @RajeshS  Thanks!  If you make this an answer, I will hit the accept button.

Comment: ,, now check my post,,, glad to help you,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Follow these command sequence, prevents Excel to update the linked chart if & when filter or update related data set.*

1. Hit **F**ile Tab then **O**ption.
2. Select & click **F**ormula.
3. Now, from pop up dialogue find, **W**orkbook Calculation Option.
4. And set it to **M**anual.

*If you are using older version of Excel then use this sequence.*

**F**ormula,, **C**alculation,, **O**ptions,, **M**anual.

**N.B.**

*During this use **F9** to recalculate formula in cell/cells.*